# How to send user password via email after admin created an user account using asp.net Identity 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

In my application admin can create user.If a user successfully created then user will get an email with a default password that was set by admin.I can send email using asp.net identity.But how can i add default password to email from database.Thanks

Comment: Despite being a bad idea to email passwords around - why not send a password reset token instead, you'd have to send the password before it is written to the DB, as you won't be able to get an unencrypted version back out.

Comment: See [Alternatives to sending out passwords in plain text via e-mail?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43915/alternatives-to-sending-out-passwords-in-plain-text-via-e-mail)